# Escaped dolls meet Sugar Jack

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am looking for an anthologized fantasy short story in which two dolls escape from their playroom into an enchanted forest. Living in the forest is a manic, toothless creature named Sugar Jack, who subsists entirely on sugar. As he eats sugar, he gets madder, stronger, and faster, chanting "Sugar chugger, sugar chugger, sugarchugger sugarchugger sugarchugger."

The escaped dolls are very like Raggedy Ann and Raggedy Andy, and the enchanted forest is like that in those books, but gone wrong.

I have a very vague impression that the anthology may have been all original stories, in imitation of Ellison's *Dangerous Visions* anthologies. It was published at least thirty years ago.

Comment: Hmm...  I knew I'd heard the term; a ["sugar jack"](https://www.gettyimages.ie/detail/photo/sugar-jack-of-the-1900s-state-canada-of-high-res-stock-photography/593388054) is a place, not a person...

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot This is taken from [here](https://whatwasthatbook.livejournal.com/1763256.html), which says a short story.

Comment: @Stormblessed It isn't necessarily _"taken"_ from there as this has extra information. Presumably the OP found that post whilst searching themselves, as it's the only relevant result, and "borrowed" some of the wording from there.

Comment: Could it have been a comic strip? Han Ola contains a flapjack tree that poisons its eaters

Comment: He sounds like a steam train!

Comment: That LIvejournal post is a friend of mine trying to help me out the last time I went around asking about this story. Sugar Jack came back to my mind because I was wondering if he is one of Neil Gaiman's Jacks of All Trades, after reflecting on how many country songs personify Jack Daniels.

Comment: This fantasy short story - which included the character 'Jack Sugar Shack(?)' did come from at least one anthology. As I recall, included in the same anthology, is a story about a newly arrived ambassodor from Earth who arrives at a planet inhabitated by a people that determine status by how much pain one can endure. The Earth ambassodor agrees to undergo torture and survives more than any of the other previous ambassadors or inhabitants and is named their leader.
Unfortunately, I do not remember the name of the author, the story, or the name of the anthology.

Answer (score 4):

["The Dolls: A Tragic Romance"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?95861), a novelette by [Ronald Anthony Cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Anthony_Cross) in the 1981 original-stories anthology [*The Berkley Showcase: Vol. 3*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?35642), edited by [Victoria Schochet](https://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/schochet_victoria) and [John Silbersack](https://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/silbersack_john).

**The dolls are Bronzino and Barbi:**

> Bronzino Red Nose was a cloth doll, made of a sturdy substance like canvas. A long pointed bright red nose jutted out from the middle of his round face, and his eyes were not shoe-button eyes but were painted on. They were large, rather sad-looking eyes. And his mouth was perennially fixed in a lugubrious smile whenever humans were about.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> And then Bronzino found her. It was Barbi the airline hostess he loved and somehow had always loved and would always love. Even when he had not known what love was, he had been directed toward her and she toward Bronzino. It was clear now in this moment of passion. They were constructed so differently: she was smooth, always at ease, cool American plastic, which drew them together into one working unit. Apart they were destined to narrow extremes that led to lonely closets: together they were a complete expression of duality unified by concern for each other: from now on he would view the whole world through his concern for her, and with this realization the whole world came to life for him in an incredible burst of blazing glory.

**They escape into the magic woods:**

> A few moments later and our two lovers, hand in hand, had slipped away from the others to the open window (Mr. Jones had been hoping someone would peek in and catch him and Mrs. Jones performing on little Billy's bed), and then out the window, across the yard, through the orchard and into the deep deep woods.
>
> For a long time the two just walked through the woods hand in hand, speechless, in awe of the beauty and depth that the woods had taken on.
>
> Once they came through a thicket of trees and saw a meadow in the moonlight, a field of flowers. Butterflies or moths, or perhaps both—this was the magic woods—were dancing in the moonlight, or were they?

**The dolls meet Sugar Jack:**

> Then he heard it coming from a great distance: a powerful voice shouting like a locomotive, "Sugar chugger, sugar chugger, sugar chugger"—closer and closer until the whole house trembled from its incredible resonance.
>
> And suddenly the house pulsed as if from an explosion, cansing Bronzino to cry out in pain: a funny little man had run into it at full tilt and smashed his head clear through the wall opposite Bronzino's crucifixion scene. He swiveled his head around and comically pursed his lips in an expression of puzzlement: he obviously had no teeth.
>
> "Hey, it's me. Crazy Jack Sugar Sack. Sugar sugar sugar. Ha ha ha. Love it. Love that white pure sweet shit. Are you Jesus Christ? Heard a you. You're A-okay with me, boy. Oughta eat more sugar though. Gives ya strength. Can't get no knives in my hands. I'm too strong—too strong—ha ha ha—sugar sugar sugar."

**Acknowledgment.** This answer was found by following a suggestion in [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217481/escaped-dolls-meet-sugar-jack#comment762621_217481) by [RagedyAnn](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/165257/ragedyann):

> This fantasy short story - which included the character 'Jack Sugar Shack(?)' did come from at least one anthology. As I recall, included in the same anthology, is a story about a newly arrived ambassodor from Earth who arrives at a planet inhabitated by a people that determine status by how much pain one can endure. The Earth ambassodor agrees to undergo torture and survives more than any of the other previous ambassadors or inhabitants and is named their leader. Unfortunately, I do not remember the name of the author, the story, or the name of the anthology.

The story about the tortured ambassador is [Piers Anthony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piers_Anthony)'s novelette ["On the Uses of Torture"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63782) which was originally published in this *Berkley Showcase* anthology and reprinted only in his collection [*Anthonology*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?257598).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the OP's description and RagedyAnn's answer/question, I would suggest that the anthology is *The Berkley Showcase: Volume 3* (1981).

The story that RagedyAnn is describing is "On the Uses of Torture" by Piers Anthony and the story the OP is looking for is "The Dolls: A Tragic Romance" by Ronald Anthony Cross.

[ISFDB link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?35642)

Comment: I had arrived at the same conclusion but was not going to post an answer until I could verify with a physical copy of the book, since I couldn't find the text online. Can you provide matching details from the story? Is Sugar Jack in it?